# Is there any publication of “Beilinson’s dream” on motivic (complexes of) sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-k-theory, algebraic-cycles

In "Standard conjectures of algebraic cycles" nLab says:

> "... They were also followed by “Beilinson’s dream” on motivic (complexes of) sheaves which comprise so called standard conjectures of Beilinson..."

Did Beilinson publish something of this work?

Which are the publications about this work?

Comment: The relevant nLab entry which has further pointers is here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Beilinson+conjecture . A link to this was missing at "standard conjectures", but I have added it now, thanks for the alert. In general, if you have questions or comments on content of nLab entries (e.g. as in this case "is there a pointer to more information missing here?") then a good place to post them  is the nForum, which is "the talk pages of the nLab" http://nforum.mathforge.org

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Comment: Possibly, you could be interested in my paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "Beilinson Conjectures" turns up several good surveys, starting with [this](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~nekovar/pu/mot.pdf) and [this](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ajs1005/preprints/d-s.pdf).  These in turn will point you to the canonical sources:  Soule's Bourbaki seminar, Ramakrishnan (Contemporary Mathematics 83) and the compendium of articles edited by Rapoport, Schappacher and Schneider.

Comment: Maybe the three origiginal papers of Beilinson would deserve to be quoted as a reference: `Higher regulators and values of L-functions', Journal of Soviet Mathematics 30 (1985), 2036-2070 and `Higher regulators of curves', Funct. Anal . Appl. 14 (1980), 116-118 and `Height pairing between algebraic cycles' in 
K-Theory, Arithmetic and Geometry,
Lecture Notes in Mathematics Volume 1289, 1987, pp 1-26.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski:  I should of course have mentioned these, though back when I was struggling to understand this, I found Soule and Ramakrishnan easier to follow.  Your mileage, of course, may vary.